# Remove Remote Fork

Tags: git, github

I want to remove the bitbucket tracking branch. I'm not sure the terminology I'm using is correct, so that might contribute to why I haven't been able to Google for a solution.

This is what I have:

```
tom@thinkpad:~/example$ git remote -v
bitbucket   git@bitbucket.org:TomLeo/example.git (fetch)
bitbucket   git@bitbucket.org:TomLeo/example.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:TomLeo/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TomLeo/example.git (push)
```

This is what I want:

```
tom@thinkpad:~/example$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:TomLeo/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TomLeo/example.git (push)
```

Comment: In general, you can look at the documentation for a Git command with `git help <command>`, e.g. `git help remote`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run:

`git remote remove bitbucket`

From the git-remote man page:

> git remote remove < name >
>
> remove, rm
>
> ```
>    Remove the remote named <name>. All remote-tracking branches and configuration settings for the remote are removed.
> ```

Comment: This has no effect on the state of the report repository correct? Only the reference to the remote branch on my local machine is removed.

Comment: @Tom yes, it only removes the tracking part, it does not affect the repo it self.

Comment: This does affect your repo config, git is distributed and each repo, bare or otherwise, is a complete repository. Your remotes are local references to external repositories. By removing a remote, you are only affecting your local reference, not disturbing the remote repository.